# How to force a constexpr function to be evaluated at compile time

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

Given the following code:

```
constexpr int omg() { return 42; }

const int a = omg(); // NOT guaranteed to be evaluated at compile time

constexpr const int a = omg(); // guaranteed to be evaluated at compile time
```

Is there a way to force something to be evaluated at compile time without assigning it to something constexpr (or in a compile time context like a template parameter ot enum shenanigans)?

Something like this:

```
const int a = force_compute_at_compile_time(omg());
```

perhaps something like this (which doesn't compile - I'm not much into constexpr yet):

```
template<typename T> constexpr T force_compute_at_compile_time(constexpr const T& a) { return a; }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use non-type template arguments:

```
template <int N> constexpr int force_compute_at_compile_time();

const int a = force_compute_at_compile_time<omg()>();
```

Since `N` is a template argument, it *has* to be a constant expression.

Comment: And is it possible to deduce that ```int``` from the expression? I'm looking for a general purpose wrapper that can force any constexpr function to be evaluated at compile time - not just the ones returning int

Comment: Doesn't this only work for integral values?

Comment: It'll only work for types which can be used as non-type template parameters, so integral types, references, pointers, enums and pointers to member. The `int` can be deduced in C++17, but before that you'd need to add another template parameter and do `force_compute_etc<decltype(omg()), omg()>();`.

Comment: @TartanLlama So even with the decltype stuff if it is returning a constexpr custom string class - it wouldn't be possible - because it's not usable as a non-type template parameter? sad...